# Object modification inconsistency on Play framework 2.2.X

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

Here's the deal:

```
public static List<Survey> getFilteredSurveys(Municipality municipality, Company company) {
    String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id FROM survey INNER JOIN " +
                    "(SELECT SURVEY_ID FROM publicity INNER JOIN brand "+
                    "ON publicity.brand_id=brand.id WHERE brand.company_id="+company.getId()+") "+
                    "ON survey_id=survey.id WHERE survey.municipality_id="+municipality.getId();
    RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql).create();
    List<Survey> surveys = Ebean.find(Survey.class).setRawSql(rawSql).findList();
    for (Survey survey : surveys) {
        List<Publicity> publicities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Publicity publicity : survey.publicities) {
            if(publicity.getBrand().getCompany() == company){
                publicities.add(publicity);
            }
        }
        survey.setPublicities(publicities);
    }
    return surveys;
}
```

This app is meant for measuring Publicities in a given place,
So people upload a 'Survey' of a place containing all the 'Publicity' that place has.

That function is supposed to return a List, 
Each Survey has a List,
And each Publicity has a Brand, which is associated to a Company (ex. Coke -> Coca Cola Co.)

What I'm trying to do is this: 
Given a Company, show all the surveys that contain a 'Coca Cola Co.' publicity, but showing only the publicities that belong to 'Coca Cola Co.'

I have a 'Surveys' controller which receives a form with a Municipality and a Company, calls this method, and it renders a view with its result.

This is part of the view template:

```
@(surveys: java.util.List[Survey])

    @for(survey <- surveys){
        @for(publicity <- survey.getPublicities){
            <tr>
                <td>@publicity.getBrand.getName</td>
                <td>@publicity.getType.getName</td>
                <td>@publicity.getSquareMeters</td>
            </tr>
    }
}
```

Problem: even though I removed some publicities from each Survey, all the publicities show up in the view. Why is this happening? 
I know I'm not persisting the changes, and I don't want to, I just want to temporarily obfuscate the data so the user only sees the publicities that belong to a given company.
Why isn't this view using the surveys as they are given to it, modified?

Comment: I think the comparison in the following `if` is not correct `if(publicity.getBrand().getCompany() == company)`. From your `company` param it seems like Company `Object` but you comparing it using `==` which should be valid for `Integers` for `Object` you should use `.equals`. This might help you..

Comment: @Sivakumar, thank you, but I already checked the result of this method, and the resulting publicities are what I expected, only the ones that belong to the given company.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'll put this in an answer ...

You should look at the SQL executed in the log (because I suspect you are getting N+1) here and you could fairly easily avoid that.

You should probably look to change your raw sql to include the publicities columns in the select clause (name, type, squareMeters) to avoid the extra queries.

Alternatively you could add fetch("publicities") to the query (so that they are fetched eagerly via a query join 100 at a time).

Also refer to:
https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/223
... RawSql that includes a OneToMany not working

https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/224
... Enhancement adding RawSqlBuilder.tableAliasMapping()

Ideally you'd be able to use 4.5.2 and take advantage of that fix and that enhancement.

Answer (score -1):

So, I found a fix, 
My fix was:

```
for (Survey survey : surveys) {
        survey.getAddress(); //This line fixes the issue
        List<Publicity> publicities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Publicity publicity : survey.publicities) {
            if(publicity.getBrand().getCompany() != null){
                if(publicity.getBrand().getCompany().getId().equals(company.getId())){
                    publicities.add(publicity);
                }
            }
        }
        survey.setPublicities(publicities);
    }
```

My guess is that the problem resides in the way ebean lazily instantiates objects, despite setting Publicities to `FetchType.EAGER`, and the fact that the output from this function was the expected one, also inspecting `surveys` in the controller seemed to be ok, and also a `@println(surveys)` in the view showed only the publicities corresponding to the company I had selected.

Comment: It looks like survey.publicities is field access and doesn't invoke lazy loading (well, wouldn't normally but might based on Play enhancement).

Comment: Just to say... you don't need to "guess" about lazy loading with Ebean. Turn on logging and in the logs you will see in a query summary log entry type[+lazy] ... and also extra stuff in there to point back to the "origin query".  So really there is no need to guess on that.